# Can't connect to database after Python and SQLAlchemy updates

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an SQLite database in a virtual environment using Python 3.10, Flask 2.1.3 and Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.5.1 (depending on Flask-SQLAlchemy 1.4.40). I wanted to try Python build 3.11 for the improved error log so I can configure a new interpreter in PyCharm to which I switch and if it didn't work to simply switch back.

I installed the newest versions of used packages, not really thinking about what that would do (that showed me ...). Now I have Flask 2.2.2 and Flask-SQLAlchemy 3.0.2 and am unable to connect to the SQLite database. When I use my 3.10 interpreter everything works, when I switch to the 3.11 interpreter, every time I try to access the database I get:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file

I wasn't able to find out what's wrong. When I setup a new project according to Flask-SQLAlchemy documentation everything works with the interpreter.

init for the app:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap5

db = SQLAlchemy()
SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(32)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database/testdb.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = SECRET_KEY
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'localhost:5000'

db.init_app(app)

Bootstrap5(app)

migrate = Migrate(app, db, render_as_batch=True)

from Connector.routes import routes
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the discrepancy is the SQLALCHEMY_Database_URI. FLASK-SQLAlchemy changed the file location when configuring a sqlite-database with a relative path:

> Configuring SQLite with a relative path is relative to app.instance_path instead of app.root_path. The instance folder is created if necessary

Details for this can be found in the [Flask-SQLAlchemy changelog for version 3.0](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/changes/#version-3-0-0)

My directory-structure:

```
Flask-Connector
|
|build
|Connector
    |Database
        |testdb.db
    |forms
    |Models
    |routes
    |templates
    |__init__.py
|dist
|instance
|KBVDefinition
|migrations
|static
|tests
|venv(310)
|venv(311)
.gitignore
app.py
app.spec
readme.md
requirements.txt
```

This means my app.rootpath is Flask-Connector/Connector

and my app.instancepath is Flask-Connector/instance

resulting in different locations an generating the error.

i will now rethink my Projectstructure and try to find a structure which works for both versions.

Or just configure a custom relativepath, using the os module:

```
import os

dbpath = f"{os.getcwd()}\\Connector\\Database\\testdb.db"

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f"sqlite:///{dbpath}"
```